# Ethernet LEDs won't turn off when i unplug the Ethernet cable

Tags: led, ethernet, microchip, linux

I'm working on a custom board equipped with a Ka-Ro TX28 module and the LAN9500A USB to Ethernet controller without EEPROM for the network interface. Operating system is Linux (Yocto). The LAN9500A is connected to a RJ45 jack with integrated Magnetics and LEDs.

I can see the LAN9500A is detected and correct driver is loaded..., Everything works fine when a cable is plugged...

The only problem is that when I unplug the Ethernet cable from the RJ45 socket, Linux does not detect it, and the status LEDs stay ON or may be blinking... However, if I again plug the network cable, link goes down then up again and it works okay...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide PHY side schematics (from PHY to the cable) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough information. What you describe is not normal, and can be a cause of various issues:

- issues with software configuring chip working in wrong mode (e.g. external PHY mode);
- issues with hardware like you using wrong transfomer (e.g. non-symmetrical one), slightly wrong values for RX/TX pull-ups.

Please refer to [reference design](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/9500a_sch.pdf) to ensure you have correct circuit, and parts you use are correct for the chip. Reviewing [application notes](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/LAN9500A) would also may help.

If you still have issues, detail your question with circuit diagram and software settings, or apply directly to the Microchip support.

Comment: [link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/9500a_sch.pdf)

Comment: Which magnetics P/N you used in your design?

Comment: This problem was solved a long time ago.

Comment: Then please share how you solved it - in separate answer or in the body of question.

Comment: Hi BachehKaraji , Please let me know the resolution of this problem. since after unplugging the Ethernet cable, Led still glow and after reinserting cable it never work, till i reboot the power.